# oracle forms change window background color programmatically?

Tags: forms, oracle, oracle10g

I tried this :

```
   SET_WINDOW_PROPERTY('WINDOW1', BACKGROUND_COLOR, 'r191g223b191');
```

But it doesn't working at oracle forms 10g.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET_CANVAS_PROPERTY(canvas_name, property_name, value);

SET_CANVAS_PROPERTY('CANVAS3', BACKGROUND_COLOR, 'r179g230b196');
```